# Native php way to use ldap extended operations?

Tags: php, ldap

Other than using perl or command line scripts is there a native php way to call ldap's extended operations?

Answer (score 0):

You could find it on your own, but sure I can provide some info for you. Take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php.

This is entire chapter of php manual about ldap functions. Although in order to use ldap functions you need to probably recompile PHP with `--with-ldap[=DIR]`, if you're not working on Windows. In Wamp I could just enable ldap extension and it should work.


Here are some info about ldap functions enabling http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php.

Comment: Thank you.  My question is if there is a ldap_* function (or some other way), to trigger extended operations.  For example, I could craft {MD5}hash and use ldap_modify to overwrite the password field, but I would rather ldap do it internally without me creating the hash.  I'm asking about a native php way to do something akin to [python-ldap.org/...](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html?highlight=pass#ldap.LDAPObject.passwd_s) or [ldapjs.org/...](http://ldapjs.org/client.html) -see exop section.

Comment: PHP does not provide a way to use any arbitrary exop because it does not provide a way to intercept possible exop responses. It does, however, implement some of them natively, like pagination, renaming / moving objects and... well, that's it. If you do not expect a server response for your extended operation ( the exop only enables/disables some behaviour like AD's Show Deleted Objects ) you can use [ldap_set_option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php).